# Lightning CheckboxGroup

Tags: lightning-aura-components, checkbox

How to clear the Lightning checkbox group? I tried to clear it using the empty array. But the value gets set to the attribute however, on the UI the checkbox is still checked.

Option 1 -

```
component.set("v.checkValue",['']);
```

Option 2 -

```
var arr= [] ;
component.set('v.checkValue',arr);
```

Both of these are not unchecking the checkbox in the UI.

Answer (score 1):

The second method is correct. I have verified this with a MVR:

```
<aura:application extends="force:slds">
    <aura:attribute name="options" type="List" />
    <aura:attribute name="value" type="List" />

    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.init}" />

    <lightning:checkboxGroup label="Test" name="test" options="{!v.options}" value="{!v.value}" />

    <lightning:button label="Reset" onclick="{!c.reset}" name="reset" />
</aura:application>
```

---

```
({
    init: function(component, event, helper) {
        component.set("v.options", [
            { label: "Hello", value: "Hello" },
            { label: "World", value: "World" }
        ]);
    },
    reset: function(component, event, helper) {
        component.set("v.value", []);
    }
})
```

It's entirely possible that you have a typo or some other glitch in your code, *or* you're trying to set the values outside of the Aura Life Cycle. When using callbacks, make sure you use `$A.getCallback` or the aura:valueChange handlers may not fire.

Comment: Tried , it was working till last week. After the upgrade it has stopped working.

Comment: @SalesforceDev Do you get any console errors? Like I said, the code above  worked for me when I posted this answer. I can try checking in a Summer 18 org, though.

Comment: No Console errors. @sfdcfox

Answer (score 0):

I'm having problems using an apex class to populate the options.

Works fine in java but labels are missing using apex.

```
<lightning:button label="Java get Options" onclick="{!c.usejava}" name="usejava" />
            <lightning:button label="Apex get Options" onclick="{!c.useapex}" name="useapex" />
```

controller is:

```
usejava: function(component, event, helper) {
    component.set("v.TeamOptions", [
        { label: "Hello", value: "Hello" },
        { label: "World", value: "World" }
    ]);
},

useapex: function(component, event, helper) {
    var action = component.get('c.getTeamOptionsViaApex');
        action.setCallback(this, $A.getCallback(function (response) {
            var state = response.getState();
            if (state === "SUCCESS") {
                console.log("TeamOptions="+response.getReturnValue());
                component.set("v.TeamOptions",response.getReturnValue());                  
            } else if (state === "ERROR") {
                helper.onError(component, helper, response, reject);
            }
        }));

        $A.enqueueAction(action);
},
```

and the apex is

```
@AuraEnabled
public static List<String> getTeamOptionsViaApex() {
    List<String> options = new List<String>();

    String str1 = '{\'label\': \'This\', \'value\': \'this\'}';
    options.add(str1);
    str1 = '{\'label\': \'Is\', \'value\': \'is\'}';
    options.add(str1);
    str1 = '{\'label\': \'Apex\', \'value\': \'apex\'}';
    options.add(str1);


    return options;
}//getTeamOptions
```

the returned value is:

```
TeamOptions={'label': 'This', 'value': 'this'},{'label': 'Is', 'value': 'is'},{'label': 'Apex', 'value': 'apex'}
```

which (I think) looks valid and I get a change from two to three checkboxes but no labels.

[Edit/Update] I found the solution:
In the success branch I had to convert each JSon string to an object.

```
var allteams = [];
                allteams = response.getReturnValue();
                //console.log('allteams = ' + allteams);   
                var ateam;
                var newvalues = [];
                for (var i in allteams) {

                    ateam = allteams[i];
                    var obj = JSON.parse(ateam);
                    newvalues.push(obj);

                 }
                component.set('v.TeamOptions',newvalues);
```

I also altered the format of the JSon strings in the apex to:

```
@AuraEnabled
public static List<String> getTeamOptionsViaApex() {
List<String> options = new List<String>();

String str1 = '{"label": "This", "value": "this"}';
options.add(str1);
str1 = '{"label": "Is", "value": "is"}';
options.add(str1);
str1 = '{"label": "Apex", "value": "apex"}';
options.add(str1);

return options;
}//getTeamOptionsViaApex
```

Comment: Also tried a different format